# How can a web service get client information?

Tags: java, web-services, xmlhttprequest, client

I am developing a web service and a client for it. I want to get the client information from the request in the web service's code. For example, I can fetch the client IP from its HTTP request.

Is there any other parameter (like client application name) of a client except IP or client hostname which I can fetch in a web service's code? I can add any configuration in the servers to pass parameters also. I am open all solutions.

Thanks

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I implemented a web service and a client. But the client will be more in future and I want to differentiate the clients from their application names to get certificates for each of them. But i don't want to change codes, i just want to learn that is there any way to recognize the client applications like that?

Comment: you can add code to your client that will ping the server with current client information and server can then use this information

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. Actually, i am searching a solution using configurations without any code changing in client side. Solution can be a lower level of OSI or it can be a change in the servers conf. I will apply the solution for a huge system after all. I am just trying with one client and one service now. But actually in the system there are 1500 clients+services. So i don't want to change code in client side.